# Phonegap change icon not working

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying change my `Ionic` application icon to `Android`, I tried all way I found in Google, but is not working.

I setting following configuration in my `config.xml`:

```
<icon src="icon.png"/> // has not another platform partial configuration
```

and the `icon.png` (72x72) is localized in:

my-project
|__ icon.png
|__ www
|__ platform
.... etc

I tried `cordova prepare`, `cordova build android` and `cordova run android`, but anyway is not working.

How to can I change `Phonegap` application icon?

My environment:

- Windows 7 x64
- `npm -v` // 3.10.3
- `node -v` // v6.4.0
- `ionic -v` // 2.1.14
- `cordova -v` // 6.4.0
- `phonegap -v` //6.3.4
- android 4.2.2

Comment: May I suggest changing the question tags to remove node.js, since it's not relevant here? (This isn't a node.js question, although you are using npm of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the icon setting from config.xml, ensure you have your icon.png file in the `/resources` folder, then run the `ionic resources --icon` command as detailed here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

Your .png should be at least 192x192, not 72x72.

Comment: I tried this command now, it's generating icons to `/resources/android/icon` folder. I tried build the project, the icons is not coping to `platform/` folder, so I create a hook to do this job when I build project.

Comment: Now you have resource icons, you should also have a lot of matching icon entries that were added to config.xml for your platforms by the command. These icons should automatically be included when you issue a build or run command.